# Measuring area of a .stl file

Tags: mesh, image

[image]I would like to ask how can I measure a specific area which is located in a .stl file.

When I use the measure tool the statistics measure the whole .stl file and not the chosen area.

[image]

[The .stl file and with orange the area that I want to measure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPtVE.jpg).

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question ... it is not clear if you want measure surface or volume (also your original version of Q wasn't clear that you are using addon Measureit ... people think you are speaking about Measure Toll stored in Tool Shelf of Viewport).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Calculate volume

... you need a manifold (closed) mesh. Like now it is open so Blender doesn't know what is a volume. You can ...

- Shift+D (*Duplicate*) selected area and
- P (*Separate Selected*), than
- model in some way manifold object, than
- use **3D-Print Toolbox** addon to calculate a volume

[image]

---

**Note:** if you need create a manifold you can ...

... use Geometry Nodes > **Bounding Box** node to calculate volume roughly

... or **Remesh** modifier (*Smooth/Sharp*) for more precise calculation

... or for the most precise calculation - manually select top vertices and **Fill Grid**

Comment: I did but I only get mm2. when I try to calculate the volume from the measurement tools in the view sidebar

Comment: Did you follow my instructions and created manifold object from the part of mesh you want to calculate volume? Or are you really speaking about 3D-Print Toolbox feature?

Comment: Yes, I have pictures. I selected the square that I want to measure, I duplicated it, I create a manifold object of it. I changed the Units to millimetres, and then I went to Measureit tools I press the Area, and then the Show. But it only gets me mm2.

Comment: I wrote you already (and my answer highlights that) I'm not using "Measure it" tool (because it measures only surface not volume ... that is why addon displays mm2)

Comment: I also use the 3D-Print toolbox but it gives me the volume from the whole stl and not the selected.

Comment: Sorry, your comments are full of confusing informations for me. My answer is step by step solution... if it didn't solve your issue I don't know how to help. But since the answer you marked as accepted worked for you, I guess, so you  probably skipped some step. If your first image (now) is your current state, you forget to separate selection by P shortcut into a solo object. If this is not the case ask a new question with structured steps you did.and where this A failed for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the `measureit` add-on.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/measureit.html

[image: img0]

[image: img1]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what I was doing until now, and it keeps measure mm2 and not mm3.

Comment: I did all the suggested actions. But when I press the Area I get 00 mm2